# How to send out a http reponse

Tags: php, apache, httpresponse

I am a php newbie and I came across some problems when use php with apache.
   I don't want to use browser to send or receive http request so that I have to manually deal with this problem. On server side, I can use file_get_content("php://input") to extract body from the http request, but how can I build the http response? The method is "post" and I want to insert a xml string to the response body. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Example:

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

For HTTP codes, Google them up.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `echo "whatever"` will return that back to the users browser. Remember that PHP is an interpreted language originally for inline scripting (i.e. mixing with HTML) prior to sending to the browser. So a file:

```
<?php echo "here"; ?>
```

will just return that reply to the users browser when they go to the appropriate URL. Adding any parsing etc. can be done in addition to this basic application logic.

Comment: Is there still confusion?